# How to implement an OnClick action on a MatTable row?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to implement an OnClick on a row with reference. If i click on a row with user 1 i want to go so see details of user 1
For example, if I click on the row of user1, I want to access the information stored in the row for this user1.

This is the html file :

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Country </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.country}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="onClick(row)" >{{row.onClickAction}}</tr>
</table>
```

And this is the ts file :

```js
export class AppComponent {
    onClickAction = '';
    onClick(){
        this.onClickAction = 'Action';
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you use expandable table, so If you click on an row, it will expand and show users info. See the Table with expandable rows on this example: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: you can use router.navigate if details are on different page

Comment: @Praetorian1995 i take the data from a server and i made a getter for clients and a getter for appointments :  this.patientRestService.getPatientDetails()
    .subscribe
    (
      data =>
      {
        this.dataSource.data = data;
      }
    );
    // this.patientRestService.getModelAppointment()
    // .subscribe
    // (
    //   data =>
    //   {
    //     this.row.data = data;
    //   }
    // );    I cant use dataSource for both and I can't put 2 parametters in the table :  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

Comment: @akaMishu yes you can, I had this in my previous project when on expandTable element click I was getting the data from my backend. I can show you an example if you want. I had it even "worst", on expand click, I was loading another table in that expanded area.

Comment: @Praetorian1995 Yeah , sure i would love to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this , now you will have access to row data and use `router` service to navigate to another component.

*template*

```
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="clickHandler(row)"> 
 </tr>
```

*component*

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  clickHandler(row) {
       this._router.navigateByUrl(`user/${row.id}`);
       console.log(row)
  }

}
```

*detail component*

```js
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public selectedUserId : string;
  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.selectedUserId = params.id;
    })
  }

}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpphih)

**Updated**‍♂️

in case you want to send a complex object between the routes you can a shared service ([singleton services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)) , or in case you using angular version 7.3 and above navigate accept another parameter with type `NavigationExtras` has a property called state accept an object later , after we navigate to the target component we can  get the value of state from history object `window.history.state`

master

```
  clickHandler(row) {
   this._router.navigate([`details`,row.position] , {state:{...row} }); 
  }
```

details

```
 this.user = window.history.state;
```

you can use `window.history.state` or the router service to get the state value

[**demo ☕☕**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-share-object)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Can i pass the info from onClick on another table right next to the main one ? To see the details kind of table popup

Comment: @akaMishu check the demo where i pass the id (position) to the detail component

Comment: @akaMishu I have update the answer again  and include a new way to pass a complex object between the routes you may need it 

Answer (score 1):

If you pass data in in the html `(click)="onClick(row)"` you can use that in your method:

```js
onClick(rowData) {
  console.log(rowData);
  this.onClickAction = 'Action';
}
```